# How can I optimize my implementation of the "toExponential" algorithm to improve precision?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, implementation, ecma262

I feel like my implementation is a bit naive. Take notice of the variables `min` in `max` which have a rather small precision of **+/-** *0.0001*. If I raise the precision any further the code is just too slow.

### Algorithm

[alt text http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/2060/toexponential.jpg](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/2060/toexponential.jpg)

### Code

```
private IDynamic ToExponential(Engine engine, Args args)
{
    var x = engine.Context.ThisBinding.ToNumberPrimitive().Value;

    if (double.IsNaN(x))
    {
        return new StringPrimitive("NaN");
    }

    var s = "";

    if (x < 0)
    {
        s = "-";
        x = -x;
    }

    if (double.IsPositiveInfinity(x))
    {
        return new StringPrimitive(s + "Infinity");
    }

    var f = args[0].ToNumberPrimitive().Value;
    if (f < 0D || f > 20D)
    {
        throw new Exception("RangeError");
    }

    var m = "";
    var c = "";
    var d = "";
    var e = 0D;
    var n = 0D;

    if (x == 0D)
    {
        f = 0D;
        m = m.PadLeft((int)(f + 1D), '0');
        e = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!args[0].IsUndefined) // fractionDigits is supplied
        {
            var lower = (int)Math.Pow(10, f);
            var upper = (int)Math.Pow(10, f + 1D);
            var min = 0 - 0.0001;
            var max = 0 + 0.0001;

            for (int i = lower; i < upper; i++)
            {
                for (int j = (int)f; ; --j)
                {
                    var result = i * Math.Pow(10, j - f) - x;
                    if (result > min && result < max)
                    {
                        n = i;
                        e = j;
                        goto Complete;
                    }
                    if (result <= 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                for (int j = (int)f + 1; ; j++)
                {
                    var result = i * Math.Pow(10, j - f) - x;
                    if (result > min && result < max)
                    {
                        n = i;
                        e = j;
                        goto Complete;
                    }
                    if (result >= 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var min = x - 0.0001;
            var max = x + 0.0001;

            // Scan for f where f >= 0
            for (int i = 0; ; i++)
            {
                // 10 ^ f <= n < 10 ^ (f + 1)
                var lower = (int)Math.Pow(10, i);
                var upper = (int)Math.Pow(10, i + 1D);
                for (int j = lower; j < upper; j++)
                {
                    // n is not divisible by 10
                    if (j % 10 == 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // n must have f + 1 digits
                    var digits = 0;
                    var state = j;
                    while (state > 0)
                    {
                        state /= 10;
                        digits++;
                    }
                    if (digits != i + 1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Scan for e in both directions
                    for (int k = (int)i; ; --k)
                    {
                        var result = j * Math.Pow(10, k - i);
                        if (result > min && result < max)
                        {
                            f = i;
                            n = j;
                            e = k;
                            goto Complete;
                        }
                        if (result <= i)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    for (int k = (int)i + 1; ; k++)
                    {
                        var result = i * Math.Pow(10, k - i);
                        if (result > min && result < max)
                        {
                            f = i;
                            n = j;
                            e = k;
                            goto Complete;
                        }
                        if (result >= i)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    Complete:

        m = n.ToString("G");
    }

    if (f != 0D)
    {
        m = m[0] + "." + m.Substring(1);
    }

    if (e == 0D)
    {
        c = "+";
        d = "0";
    }
    else
    {
        if (e > 0D)
        {
            c = "+";
        }
        else
        {
            c = "-";
            e = -e;
        }
        d = e.ToString("G");
    }

    m = m + "e" + c + d;
    return new StringPrimitive(s + m);
}
```

### Final Version

I swear someone must have hit me with a particularly large hammer back when I originally wrote this...

```
private IDynamic ToExponential(Engine engine, Args args)
{
    var x = engine.Context.ThisBinding.ToNumberPrimitive().Value;

    if (args[0].IsUndefined)
    {
        return new StringPrimitive(x.ToString("0.####################e+0"));
    }

    var f = args[0].ToNumberPrimitive().Value;

    if (f < 0D || f > 20D)
    {
        RuntimeError.RangeError("The parameter fractionDigits must be between 0 and 20.");
    }
            
    return new StringPrimitive(x.ToString("0." + string.Empty.PadRight((int)f, '0') + "e+0"));            
}
```

Comment: what kind of language is this? :)

Comment: @galambalazs - Do you mean the language for my engine? If so it is ECMAScript which is more commonly known as JavaScript or JScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compute `result = i * Math.Pow(10, j - f) - x` you're trying to find where `result` is 0. Since `j`, `f`, and `x` are know, you just need to solve for `i`. Rather than writing a loop to find `i`, you can just say

`i * Math.Pow(10, j - f) = x` => `i = x / Math.Pow(10, j - f)`

The value you need should be either `floor(i)` or `ceil(i)`.

Just out of curiosity, have you checked to see if `ToString("e")` gives you the correct answer?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test your answer until I return from my CRUD day job. To answer your question, I did check if `ToString("e")` would work by comparing the results to Firefox's implementation and they were quite different. Plus despite the bad implementation it was quite fun to write.

Comment: Oh man I just realized this is basic algebra we are talking about here. */facepalm*

Comment: I feel quite silly... My guess is I gave up to soon when trying to use the built-in number formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by using `Math.Log10`, rather than a loop, to find the exponent.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail? I'm feeling a bit slow today.

Comment: Despite the lack of details you did force me to think which deserves an up-vote. :)